# Streamline groupby process

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and seeking advice to make my code more effective.

I have a Dataframe (df) with 10 columns, lets say A,B,C,D......J

I want to groupby A and B,C,D.... then sum J which is a numerical sampling value.

I have this code that does exactly what I want it to, but I am looking for a way to streamline the process - I was thinking in a loop, rather than copying this line of code for each column.
Here df is the Dataframe containing the 10 columns.

```
Ex1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['J'].sum().transpose().reset_index()
Ex2 = df.groupby(['A', 'C'])["J"].sum().transpose().reset_index()
....

Ex9 = df.groupby(['A', 'I'])["J"].sum().transpose().reset_index()
```

I have tried

```
test = pd.DataFrame()
for columnData in df.iteritems():
    y = df.groupby(["A", columnData])["J"].sum().transpose().reset_index()
    test.append(y)
```

and a few other variations.

The result should look like:

```
  A   B   C ..... J
 100  x   y       # 
 101  x   y       #
 105  x   y       #
 ...  ... ...   ...
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What is `df` and what should `test` look like?/what is the expected output?

Comment: Hello, I added this to the post. df is the Dataframe with the 10 columns and an example of what it should look like - Thanks